# Changing column format

Tags: r, datetime, formatting, format, datetime-format

I want to change column type into a date-time one. The data in an xlsx file looks like this:

```
"2012-05-22 22:03:14"
```

R identifies it as a character variable.

I have attempted with following R codes:

```
as.Date(data$tempus, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
as.POSIXlt(data$tempus, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
format(as.Date(data$tempus, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
```

Nevertheless, when checking the data format with

```
typeof(data$tempus)
```

R yields: `"character"`.

Comment: Are you saving the modified column back to the `data.frame`?

Comment: As manotheshark said, remember to reassign the column `data$columnnamehere <- as.Date(data$columnnamehere, "%y-%m-%d")`

Comment: I did not before, now I have commanded: data$tempus <- as.Date(data$tempus, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"). When checking the column type this time it yields: "double"... Is that correct? I mean, is there in R a column type that is named as "time"/"date-time", etc.?

Comment: Try doing `data$tempus <- as.POSIXct(data$tempus)` and then check `class(data$tempus)` it should give you `"POSIXct"` class

Comment: Finally, the desired effect is achieved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough credits to comment hence answer.
My favourite library for dates is Lubridate

```
t<-"2012-05-22 22:03:14"
str(t)
library(lubridate)
t<-ymd_hms(t, tz= "Asia/Kolkata")
str(t)
t
```

You just have to give the right format of your input. Lubridate takes care of everything. You dont have to write %h or %D never ever.

Also use str() command to find out type of the data.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has helped you. thanks